# CSS3 transitions - Javascript library

Tags: css, javascript, transition

Does somebody know a little Javascript librabry that will mimic CSS3 transitions for browsers like Firefox 3.6 or IE8?

Example:

```
-webkit-transition:left 1s ease-in;
```

I guess such a library is quite hard to develop.

These two support a lot but no CSS3 transitions:

- [CSSsandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/)
- [CSSPie](http://css3pie.com/)

And then we have [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) but it only does feature testing.

The great thing about having an extra mini library for CSS3 transitions support is that you don't need to write your own backup code. You could just plug it in and be sure that those transitions work in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can try using JQuery animation to mimic the effect, but it still requires some coding. Nothing as simple as CSS3 code for transitions ;(

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same library and didn't succeed, so I decided to create it.
Hope that's what you wanted - [**alevkon / smooth**](http://github.com/alevkon/smooth/).

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've open sourced a JavaScript library that may help your with your question. It and published under http://transitionjs.org

It allows you to quickly apply CSS transition on elements from JavaScript without editing your CSS. For example, to execute CSS transition you mentioned in your question you would simply write:

```
transitionjs.begin(element, 'left 0px 100px 1s ease-in');
```

note: you will need to provide the start and end values of the transition.